# android, unbind service with sub-threads

Tags: android, service

A have bound service which creates sub-threads for some work.
When I call unbindService of the last client from activity, how sub-threads in service will behave?

1. Will they be interrupted?
2. Will service wait until sub-threads finish their work?
3. Other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other. `Service` itself will be in destroyed state and so process will more likely to be killed by the system. `Threads` themselves will continue to do their job, but if they are anonymous or inner classes they will keep a reference to your `Service` (thus creating a memory leak). You are not guaranteed to have `Threads` finish before the process is killed.